# Bootstrap modal, stop movie on close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a jsfiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/nbuo8crd/26/

I'm using a bootstrap modal to play a video.

The movie has a close button that closes the modal and removes/stops the video.

If I click anywhere off the modal the modal closes but the movie continues to play.

What event can I use when you click off the modal (which closes it) to remove/stop the movie playing.

```
    $('.js-play').click(function(){
        var vid_num = $(this).data('vid');
        var vid_src = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/'+vid_num+'/?autoplay=true';

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#myModal iframe').attr('src', vid_src);
    })

    $('#videoToggleOff').click(function(){
        $('iframe#myVideo').attr('src','');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bootstrap 3**

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

Refer: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events